# query for date range '01-01-2019' and '02-02-2019' is not working

Tags: mysql

I have a query with date range like between '01-01-2019' and '03-02-2019' and it is working while I change  day(02)  of date range like '01-01-2019' and  '02-02-2019' then Query is not working.

I have a query with date range from  '01-01-2019' and To :  '03-02-2019' like

```
SELECT * FROM `customer_info` WHERE `rec_date` between '01-01-2019'  and  '03-02-2019'
```

so it is working but when I change the day of date range like  from '01-01-2019' and To : '02-02-2019'  and query is

```
SELECT * FROM `customer_info` WHERE `rec_date` between '01-01-2019'  and  '02-02-2019'
```

But query is not working.

I want from this query that it should fetch records after changing day of date range of TO : '02-02-2019'.Please tell me solution why it is not fetching records.

Comment: what is not working?are you getting any error?

Comment: which data type is rec_date ???

Comment: In MySQL, the default syntax of dates is `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Mysql stores dates in date datatype column in the form yyyy-mm-dd. if rec_date is a date datatype then you can compare with a string in the form yyyy-mm-dd. If rec_date is not a data datatype then you need to convert all terms to yyyy-mm-dd possibly using str_to_date

Comment: specify data type of field and format of it.

Comment: Use correct format of date as 'YYYY-mm-dd'

Answer (score 0):

That rec_date is probably a VARCHAR or CHAR type instead of a DATE type.

Then it should be transformed to a DATE type before getting a range from that.
Otherwise the BETWEEN will compare the strings alphabetically.

And when you then query a date range, use the 'YYYY-MM-DD' format for date constants.
That won't lead to a confusion with the months and days.
*(Is '01-04-2019' the 1st of April, or the 4th of January?)*

```
SELECT * 
FROM `customer_info` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(rec_date,'%m-%d-%Y') BETWEEN '2019-01-01' and '2019-03-02'
```

Comment: Dear Sir , I will be selecting data between January 1 and February 2. then data is available in a database and it  is indicating that  there is no data between  January 1 and February 2 while I will be selecting data between January 1 and February 3 then it is indicating that there is a data between January 1 and February 3.So Please tell me why is it indicating that there is not data between January 1 and February 2

Comment: What data type is rec_date? And are you sure that '03-02-2019' doesn't mean 2nd of March 2019? Because with a month difference, it could be that you're simply missing 1 month data?

Answer (score 0):

***With Only Date:***
MySQL date format is this : YYYY-MM-DD. In a simple way it can be queried as

```
select * from customer_info where rec_date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-02-02'
```

OR

```
select * from customer_info where rec_date between >= '2019-01-01' and '2019-02-02'
```

***With Date & Time:***
Just use the format which MySQL handles dates YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS and have the query as

```
select * from customer_info where rec_date >= '2019-01-01' and rec_date <= '2019-02-02'
```

Especially since MySQL now supports sub-second time precision. Using 23:59:59 is one full second short of the end of a day. where rec_date >= '2019-01-01' and rec_date <= '2019-02-02' is the most precise way to define a date range and will work for any level of time precision from date to sub-second units.

OR

Simple as that.

```
select * from customer_info where rec_date between '2019-01-01 00:00:00' and '2019-02-02 23:59:00'
```